# How to change case in an element inside a sublist in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, case, sublist

I'm new in Python and I was trying to change the case in a list of lists with mixed elements. I would like to change the fourth element in every sublist with title function
The list is something like this:

```
records = [2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'SOPHIA', 223, 3],  
 [2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'SOPHIE', 12, 76],  
 [2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'STACY', 10, 78],  
 [2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'STELLA', 11, 77],  
.......
```

The result I would like to get is something like this:

```
records = [2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'Sophia', 223, 3],  
 [2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'Sophie', 12, 76],  
 [2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'Stacy', 10, 78],  
 [2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'Stella', 11, 77],  
.......
```

I was trying to do this:

```
     `for row in range(records):`  
      `row[3].title()`
```

but I get the following error:

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
I would be grateful If someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there!

Considering the input as:

```
records = [[2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'SOPHIA', 223, 3],  
[2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'SOPHIE', 12, 76],  
[2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'STACY', 10, 78],  
[2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'STELLA', 11, 77]]
```

You can iterate over the main list this way:

```
for row in records:
    row[3] = row[3].title()
```

Or, alternatively, you can index the for loop:

```
for i in range(len(records)):
    records[i][3] = records[i][3].title()
```

Both produces the following result:

```
[[2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'Sophia', 223, 3],
 [2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'Sophie', 12, 76],
 [2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'Stacy', 10, 78],
 [2011, 'FEMALE', 'HISPANIC', 'Stella', 11, 77]]
```